# Is there any way to include autohide and on tap feature in tootip flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need both a clickable and auto-hide feature(for flutter web) tooltip when the mouse hover over a button.
I tried multiple tooltips but the problem is that when we move the cursor for clicking inside the tooltip it will hide automatically so clickable is impossible.
I used "super_tooltip"  clickable is possible but auto-hide is only possible if we click outside or click the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can use `super_tooltip` and put a `Gesture Detector` as a `child` to use on tap and with code, you can show and hide the `tooltip` after a particular time `duration`.

https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip

Comment: I called this tooltip inside the onEnter property of the Mouse region. Where will I give the time duration to hide when the mouse hover over another button?